# Lightning Web Component Custom Errors

Tags: validation, lightning-web-components

I'm trying to do some custom validation on submit for a Lightning Web Component.  I'm trying to use the `setErrors` method for a lightning-input-field (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-field/specification) and nothing seems to be happening.

Does anyone have any examples of how I can get the error message to show or know where I can find one?

```
handleSubmit(events){
    let f = this.template.querySelector('.myInputField');
    f.setErrors('error message');
    f.reportValidity();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For field "AccountId" you can use this object hierarchy to set error to lightning-input-field.

```
handleSubmit(events){
  let f = this.template.querySelector('.myInputField');
  f.setErrors({'body':{'output':{'fieldErrors':{'AccountId':[{'message':'Error'}]}}}});
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution helped me to solve my issue.

Comment: This is a very useful find! To take this one step further, use a more specific querySelector in order to target a specific field:
`let inputField = this.template.querySelector('[field-name="FIELD_API_NAME"]');`

Comment: At UI level it works, but when in handler we use reportValidity method before saving user input, it return false, so there is no point of using this solution to report error. These error are not detected by reportValidaity. It return false. If same used with lightning-input, return true.

Answer (score 2):

The description for the method `setErrors` on [`lightning-input-field`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-field/specification) mentions:

> Reserved for internal use.

I would imagine we cannot use any such attribute/method if it is reserved for internal use.

Comment: You are correct, I just missed that part when I was reading it.

Comment: @aaron It’s really easy to miss. I figured it out only when came across your question :)

Comment: While the documentation *does* say it is a method reserved for internal use, it's access is still marked as global. I don't particularly understand why they do this in the documentation, but developers can still call and use the functionality if used correctly. See the answer & replies here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/381414/63755

Comment: I think the concern about what `Reserved for internal use` means is that Salesforce isn't promising it's stable. If it means the method may become unavailable or change in some way, it would be "at your own risk" to choose to use it. It might also just mean that "you gotta use it internally, i.e. in the JS with a querySelector", but in that case I would expect the `clean` and `focus` method descriptions to be the same. Unless they simply never bothered to give them a proper description. Until someone can prove what it means, I'd definitely assume it means "use at your own risk"!

Comment: Confirmed it: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_components.htm&release=220&type=5

"attributes and methods are marked “Reserved for internal use”, and their implementation can change at any time".

So yeah, it may work for now. It may work forever. It may break tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use 'reportValidity()' of input-field. It should allow you to show error message if input is invalid.